# Pinscript error 'Syntax error at input 'strategy''

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hi this code gives a  Syntax error at input 'strategy' and I cant figure out why. Please can you help?

```
    //@version=5

    strategy("Slope", overlay=false)

    sma20 = ta.wma(close,20)
    sma200= ta.wma(close,200)
    slope20 = sma20-sma20[1]
    slope200 = sma200-sma200[1]
    angle20 = math.atan(slope20)*(180/math.pi)
    angle200 = math.atan(slope200)*(180/math.pi)

    plot( angle20 , title = "Slope", color=color.blue)
    plot( angle200 , title = "Slope", color=color.red)
    hline(0)

    if (angle200 > 0)
         strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
    if (angle200 < 0)
    //else
         strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
```

I was expecting it to compile!
I have tried replacing the second if statement with an else
I have changed the indentation
I thought it could be the number type so changed the 0 to 0.0`

Answer (score 2):

The body of the if blocks must be indented by 4 spaces. Your `strategy.entry()` and `strategy.exit()` functions are indented by 5 spaces. Remove one space and it compiles fine.

Comment: thanks @vitruvius 
simple when you know how!! I thought tabs would do it.
Now I know.